# how to use jquery to post on a page from multiple forms

Tags: jquery

I have a multiple form which follows this logic:

```
<form name='input0' id='0' action='correct_exec.php' method='GET'>
<input class='correct' type='text' name='val[0]' value='0366167'></td>
</form>
<form name='input1' id='1' action='correct_exec.php' method='GET'>
<input class='correct' type='text' name='val[1]' value='0366132'></td>
</form>
```

I have another page which when I send one of this form via get, that will update my database (of course, there are input type hidden too associated to each form but I didnt put them here and there is each time a button to submit the form).

How can I use jquery to update the form via GET instead of having a button for each form that will go to the other page and then I have to hit back each time to come back to this edit page?

Thanks,

John.

Answer (score 0):

you could use ajax.  the entire purpose of ajax is that you stay on the same form

for example your code could look like this

```
$('form#0, form#1').submit(function(){
    var name = $('.correct', this).attr('name');
    var value = $('.correct', this).val();
    $.get('correct_exec.php', {name: value}).success(function(){
        alert('data saved');
    });
    return false;
});
```

basically we prevent the forms from submitting using return false.  and instead we make an ajax call.   We grab the stuff we want to send from the form, and we submit it using javascript.